# What is the new way of obtaining current query from router context in v2.x?

Tags: react-router

I am upgrading to v2 and can't seem to find in the docs an example of how to access the current query from the router context (or other means).

Pertinent parts of the components:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;   
var routes = require('./Routes');

var browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;

var App = {
blastoff: function () {
    this.mainElement = ReactDOM.render((<Router history = {browserHistory}>{routes}</Router>),
                window.document.getElementById('app-mount')
            );
        }
};



........
contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.func
    },

.......

this.context.router.getCurrentQuery()
```

How should this be done in v2.x?  Is there a completely different way of getting the current query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not directly available via non-deprecated APIs. The `location` prop is made available to route components, and you can pass the query information down from there as appropriate.

Comment: I finally was able to piece that together by going through both upgrade guides.  There is one for 1.0 and one for 2.0, but I was trying to go from 0.13.0 to 2.x (rc4) and had to read the 1.0 guide instead of just the 2.0.  Now using 'this.props.location.query'.  Also 'this.context.router.getCurrentParams()' can be replaced with 'this.props.params'. Hope this helps someone....